# Dart 2 async package precompilation error

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I'm trying to run a web app with the Dart 2 SDK using `webdev`. I finally got the dependencies to resolve successfully, but now `pub get` cannot precompile the `async` package.

I found this issue that seems relevant, but the `pub global run` workaround they suggested did not work: https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1932

### pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  browser_detect: ^1.0.4
  dnd: ^1.2.0
  firebase: ^0.5.0
  gorgon: ^0.14.2
  intl: ^0.15.6
  jsonx: ^2.0.2
  slack: ^1.2.2
  stagexl: ^1.3.1+4
  xml: ^3.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: '>=0.8.10 <0.10.0'
  build_web_compilers: '>=0.3.6 <0.5.0'
```

### pub get

Dart VM version: 2.0.0-dev.69.0 (Unknown timestamp) on "linux_x64"

```
Resolving dependencies...
Overriding the upper bound Dart SDK constraint to <=2.0.0-dev.69.0 for the following packages:

args, async, browser, browser_detect, coUemoticons, convert, cou_toolkit, edit_distance, firebase, fixnum, glob, gorgon, graphs, http_parser, js, jsonx, libld, logging, meta, petitparser, pub_semver, quiver, quiver_iterables, scproxy, slack, source_span, stack_trace, stagexl, string_scanner, transmit, typed_data, xml

To disable this you can set the PUB_ALLOW_PRERELEASE_SDK system environment variable to `false`, or you can silence this message by setting it to `quiet`.
Got dependencies!
Precompiling executables...
Failed to precompile build_runner:graph_inspector:
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/typed/stream.dart:56:10: Error: The return type of the method 'TypeSafeStream::firstWhere' is dart.async::Future<dynamic>, which does not match the return type of the overridden method (dart.async::Future<#lib1::TypeSafeStream::T>).
Change to a subtype of dart.async::Future<#lib1::TypeSafeStream::T>.
  Future firstWhere(bool test(T element), {Object defaultValue()}) =>
         ^
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/typed/stream.dart:56:10: Error: The method 'TypeSafeStream::firstWhere' doesn't have the named parameter 'orElse' of overriden method 'Stream::firstWhere'.
  Future firstWhere(bool test(T element), {Object defaultValue()}) =>
         ^
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/typed/stream.dart:59:10: Error: The return type of the method 'TypeSafeStream::lastWhere' is dart.async::Future<dynamic>, which does not match the return type of the overridden method (dart.async::Future<#lib1::TypeSafeStream::T>).
Change to a subtype of dart.async::Future<#lib1::TypeSafeStream::T>.
  Future lastWhere(bool test(T element), {Object defaultValue()}) =>
         ^
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/typed/stream.dart:59:10: Error: The method 'TypeSafeStream::lastWhere' doesn't have the named parameter 'orElse' of overriden method 'Stream::lastWhere'.
  Future lastWhere(bool test(T element), {Object defaultValue()}) =>
         ^
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/typed/stream.dart:62:13: Error: The method 'TypeSafeStream::singleWhere' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'Stream::singleWhere'.
  Future<T> singleWhere(bool test(T element)) async =>
            ^
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/restartable_timer.dart:11:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'RestartableTimer' is missing implementations for these members:
  'tick'.
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class RestartableTimer implements Timer {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/result/capture_transformer.dart:15:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'CaptureStreamTransformer' is missing implementations for these members:
  'cast'.
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class CaptureStreamTransformer<T> implements StreamTransformer<T, Result<T>> {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/result/release_transformer.dart:12:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'ReleaseStreamTransformer' is missing implementations for these members:
  'cast'.
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class ReleaseStreamTransformer<T> implements StreamTransformer<Result<T>, T> {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/single_subscription_transformer.dart:16:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'SingleSubscriptionTransformer' is missing implementations for these members:
  'cast'.
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class SingleSubscriptionTransformer<S, T> implements StreamTransformer<S, T> {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/typed_stream_transformer.dart:23:7: Error: The non-abstract class '_TypeSafeStreamTransformer' is missing implementations for these members:
  'cast'.
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class _TypeSafeStreamTransformer<S, T> implements StreamTransformer<S, T> {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to precompile build_runner:build_runner:
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/typed/stream.dart:56:10: Error: The return type of the method 'TypeSafeStream::firstWhere' is dart.async::Future<dynamic>, which does not match the return type of the overridden method (dart.async::Future<#lib1::TypeSafeStream::T>).
Change to a subtype of dart.async::Future<#lib1::TypeSafeStream::T>.
  Future firstWhere(bool test(T element), {Object defaultValue()}) =>
         ^
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/typed/stream.dart:56:10: Error: The method 'TypeSafeStream::firstWhere' doesn't have the named parameter 'orElse' of overriden method 'Stream::firstWhere'.
  Future firstWhere(bool test(T element), {Object defaultValue()}) =>
         ^
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/typed/stream.dart:59:10: Error: The return type of the method 'TypeSafeStream::lastWhere' is dart.async::Future<dynamic>, which does not match the return type of the overridden method (dart.async::Future<#lib1::TypeSafeStream::T>).
Change to a subtype of dart.async::Future<#lib1::TypeSafeStream::T>.
  Future lastWhere(bool test(T element), {Object defaultValue()}) =>
         ^
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/typed/stream.dart:59:10: Error: The method 'TypeSafeStream::lastWhere' doesn't have the named parameter 'orElse' of overriden method 'Stream::lastWhere'.
  Future lastWhere(bool test(T element), {Object defaultValue()}) =>
         ^
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/typed/stream.dart:62:13: Error: The method 'TypeSafeStream::singleWhere' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'Stream::singleWhere'.
  Future<T> singleWhere(bool test(T element)) async =>
            ^
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/restartable_timer.dart:11:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'RestartableTimer' is missing implementations for these members:
  'tick'.
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class RestartableTimer implements Timer {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/result/capture_transformer.dart:15:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'CaptureStreamTransformer' is missing implementations for these members:
  'cast'.
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class CaptureStreamTransformer<T> implements StreamTransformer<T, Result<T>> {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/result/release_transformer.dart:12:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'ReleaseStreamTransformer' is missing implementations for these members:
  'cast'.
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class ReleaseStreamTransformer<T> implements StreamTransformer<Result<T>, T> {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/single_subscription_transformer.dart:16:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'SingleSubscriptionTransformer' is missing implementations for these members:
  'cast'.
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class SingleSubscriptionTransformer<S, T> implements StreamTransformer<S, T> {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
file:///home/andy/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/src/typed_stream_transformer.dart:23:7: Error: The non-abstract class '_TypeSafeStreamTransformer' is missing implementations for these members:
  'cast'.
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class _TypeSafeStreamTransformer<S, T> implements StreamTransformer<S, T> {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Am I doing something wrong in my `pubspec.yaml`, or is there an issue with `async` or another package? This project has worked fine for about 4 years now, but I can't get it to work in Dart 2. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are depending on several libraries that haven't been updated for Dart 2.  Unfortunately the only solution would be to remove these dependencies or move back to a Dart 1 SDK. For reference:

- browser_detect: v 1.0.4 • Updated: Mar 2, 2016
- gorgon v 0.14.2 • Updated: Dec 6, 2014
- jsonx v 2.0.2 • Updated: May 19, 2016
- slack 1.2.2 • Updated: Jun 6, 2015 WEB

In general, only libraries which were last updated sometime in 2018 will work in Dart 2, and usually only the very latest version. You can check the status of your dependencies by searching for the package name on [pub.dartlang.org](https://pub.dartlang.org/)

Edit: gorgon in particular has a dependency on an older version of `async`, I would start by removing that

Comment: In particular something is preventing you from getting `async` version 2

Comment: I removed all dependencies and added them back in one by one until it broke at gorgon. I then added everything except gorgon and it works, so I forked it and I'll update the dependencies and then depend on the git-hosted version. Thanks!